# Bower install unstable release (1.4.0-rc.0) of angular

Tags: angularjs, bower

Having trouble installing angular#1.4.0-rc.0 via bower - when I run:

```
bower install --save angular#1.4.0-rc.0
```

I get the error

```
no matches found: angular#1.4.0-rc.0
```

However running `bower update angular` shows packages that depend on 1.4.0-rc.0:

```
angular-cookies#1.4.0-rc.0 depends on angular#1.4.0-rc.0 which resolved to angular#1.4.0-rc.0
```

Adding `"angular": "~1.4.0-rc.0"` or `"angular": "1.4.0-rc.0"` doesn't help either!

Thanks guys!

Comment: Also works for me. What version of bower are you using? `bower -v`

Comment: What is the output of `bower info angular | grep 1.4.0-rc`?

Comment: delete yr previous bower_components folder or yr custom location & try again.

Comment: @ajp15243 1.4.1, fracz - 1.4.0-rc.0

going to try delete bower_components.

Comment: @nitin if you want to post as an answer I can accept it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @nitin, deleting my bower_components folder and reinstalling did the trick.

Comment: Please don't add _"thanks"_ as answers. They don't actually provide an answer to the question, and can be perceived as noise by its future visitors. Instead, [upvote answers](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) you like. This way future visitors of the question will see a higher vote count on that answer, and the answerer will also be rewarded with reputation points. See [Why is voting important](http://stackoverflow.com/help/why-vote).

Answer (score 2):

delete your previous `bower_components` folder or your custom location.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: on harepls's request i posted it as an answer.